# Trying to find a way to pass a list to an item in request.POST. How do I do it?

Tags: jquery, django

This is my html code in django project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        {% load static %}
        <script src="{% static 'jquery-3.6.2.min.js' %}" ></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button id="button1" name="action" value="">button2</button>
            <script>
                $("#button1").click(
                    function(){
                        arr = ["one", "two"]
                        $("#button1").attr('value',arr)
                    }
                )
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

By clicking the button I run JQuery that assigns an array: `arr` to button1's value.
This is request.POST afterwards:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Rws3PVVBVOGsoXm720M5YbuZNTYMin6CxklI78in2PWdrxAYKxw3XqV7cba2xt7P'], 'action': ['one,two']}>
```

Instead of `'action': ['one,two']` I want to get `'action': ['one', 'two']`, or `'action': [['one', 'two']]`

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`JSON.stringify()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert array into **JSON** string and then use [**`json.loads(...)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to load **JSON** string to convert it into **Python** object.

Your code will look like this

**JavaScript**

---

```
<script>
  $("#button1").click(
    function(){
      arr = JSON.stringify(["one", "two"])
      $("#button1").attr('value',arr)
    })
</script>
```

**Python**

---

```
import json


def foo(request):
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if action:
       print(json.loads(action)) # result -> {'action': ['one', 'two']}
```

**Note:**

> Make sure you sanitize your **`request.POST.get('action')`** data it
> may contain malisious code if it's sent by client so always validate
> your request data.